# Accessing user authentication information within a Cloud Firestore triggered Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to get signed in user id when a Cloud Function listening to change in db is triggered

I tried `firestore.getAuth()` without success.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get signed in user id when a Cloud Function listening to
> changes in db is triggered

It is not possible with Cloud Functions for Firestore to access the details of the authenticated user who did the modification that triggered the CF. One workaround is to write the user ID in a field in the Firestore document.

---

FYI note that, in the other hand, [this is possible with the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#accessing_user_authentication_information).